# C and SDL quit from function

Tags: c, function, sdl

I use C and SDL 2.0, but i have a problem, this(when you click on the window's "x" it quits):

```
void function(SDL_Surface *screen) {
  SDL_Event event;
  bool quit=false;
    while (!quit) {
            SDL_WaitEvent(&event);

            switch (event.type) {
               case...

               case SDL_QUIT:    
                  quit = true;        
                  break;
            }
}
```

This is working, but not well. If this is in a function like this, it quits only to the main(), so I need to click on "x" again to quit from the whole program.
How can I solve it? (I want to quit from the whole program everytime, does not matter if it's in a function or not).

Comment: If it quits to `main`, then what is your problem? Why don't you just return from `main` too?

Comment: I made a game (who wants to be a millionare), so this would be really annoying for users. Furthermore this want to be a homework,  and i dont want to send it in with this annoying behaviour.

Comment: I mean what issue do you have if you are able to return to `main` function? You should be able to exit terminate program just by returning from `main`.

Comment: and when you click on the "x" while the program is in a function, it returns to the main and execute the rest part of it with bad datas. So not just annoying.

Comment: So why don't you return from `main` instead of executing that code? Just `return 0;` or `return EXIT_SUCCESS;`.

Comment: @GergoMiklos it reads like you have event loop in main too. If so, this is horribly wrong. "Simple" answer would be something like `exit(1)` call, but it is most likely not "correct" one.

Comment: I share the opinion of @keltar to have many event loops, but if you want to obtain an immediate and a bit "rude" exit to the program maybe adding the `SDL_Quit();` function to the SDL_QUIT case of the switch can solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned in comments you, most probably, have multiple event handling loops, which is usually incorrect design. You game general layout should be something like:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    // do initialize stuff

    bool run = true;
    SDL_Event evt;

    // game loop
    while (run) {
        // process OS events
        while(SDL_PollEvent(&evt) != 0) {
            switch (evt.type) {
                case SDL_QUIT:    
                  run = false;        
                  break;
            }
        }

        update();
        render();
    }

    // clean up
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```